# .NET Regex issue: end-of-string char matching the dollar of the string

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having an issue with a Regex. I basically need to split a string with Chr(1) as a delimiter and each group is formatted as key=value (where key is numeric). The beginning of the string is a 3-char code and is not gathered with the Regex.
Example:

```
031|0=2013/12/04 00:03:35|400=lr5ulz1jxg8ss|3=SFE|4=2$1NNR|6=1
```

So I used the following Regexp:

```
Private Shared _RegexDeserialize As New Regex(String.Format("{0}(\d+)=([^${0}]*)", Chr(1)))
```

But when there is a dollar ($) in the value part, the rest is not matched.

Then I used the following:

```
Private Shared _RegexDeserialize As New Regex(String.Format("{0}(\d+)=([^{0}]*)", Chr(1)))
```

I don't understand why my previous Regex doesn't work properly and why VB.Net is matching the end-of-string delimiter ($) to the dollar ($) of the string. If I wanted to match to a dollar, I should have escaped it: \$

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Comment: `If I wanted to match to a dollar, I should have escaped it: \$`. Yes you answered yourself.

Comment: All characters inside a character class are treated as literal characters and not as regex meta characters, except the characters `^` and `-` which take different meanings depending on their position in the character class.

Comment: i think the correct pattern should be: "(\d+)=([^|]*)" in your example takes 5 matches and for each two groups before and after "="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...]` is a character class. Normally, `$` (along with many other characters such as `*+?)[.(|`) are *metacharacters*. However, when they are inside a character class, they become *literal characters*. This means that they lose their special meaning, so a `$` inside a character class matches `$`, not and end-of-string. Instead of `$`, you can use `\Z` which is the equivalent, but still works inside character classes.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but I *think* the regex you want is

```
\d+=[^|]+
```

Demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/rI4tM3

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't know this specificity.

Comment: Are you saying `[\Z]` matches the end of a string, just like `\Z`?  That's not true.  It's just a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your `$` is inside of `[^...]`. It can't mean end-of-string in that location, so it thinks you mean a literal `$`.

The reason this "usually" works for you is because you don't actually need the end-of-string at all :)

```
"{0}(\d+)=([^{0}]*)"
```

The `*` is greedy, it will eat up as many characters as it can, so everything works just fine :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and to confirm me that the fix-version will work properly. Much appreciated.